# mysql - using stored procedure in select statememt

Tags: mysql

I have following stored procedure :

```
mysql> call generateSerial('param1',1,@serial);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @serial;
+--------------+
| @serial      | 
+--------------+
| 100000000033 |
+--------------+
```

I want to use above @serial for each row from select query, something like:

```
select @serial ,...
from table_test;
```

and with each row, @serial are difference by difference procedure execute

I know that procedure can not be executed in select stm

But I also can not using function because I need using a transaction to get @serial

have any chance for me about this case ;

Comment: Can you use an anonymous code block? `BEGIN ... END;`

Comment: yes ,anyway is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way creating a second procedure that loops over the table rows and calls the generate serial procedure for each row.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE run()
BEGIN

DECLARE serial VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE col_int INT;
DECLARE col_varchar VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE query CURSOR FOR SELECT column_int, column_varchar FROM t;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN query;

q: LOOP
  FETCH query into col_int, col_varchar;

  IF done THEN
    LEAVE q;
  END IF;

  CALL GenerateSerial(col_varchar,col_int,serial);

  select serial;

END LOOP;

CLOSE query;

END;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bed9d9/1)